# NavigationView and NavigationLink not deleting views after transition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am writing an app using `SwiftUI`, and I am having some issues with the `NavigationView` and the `Navigation Link`, as shown below in the simulator video. The project was created as a `Single View App`.

I have three pages, and as you can see when it takes me from one page to the other, it builds the second page under the first one, and doesn’t dellocate the first one, and I have the same problem on the third page: it is created below the second one, and I can even go back to the first page via the faulty `back` button on the top left.

Video:

[image: demo of the problem]

This is the code of the three pages:

`first.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct first: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: second()) {
                Text("first link")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct first_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        first()
    }
}
```

`second.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct second: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: third()) {
                Text("second link")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct second_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        second()
    }
}
```

`third.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct third: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Third page")
    }
}

struct third_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        third()
    }
}
```

I am using the `Navigation View` in the same manner that the official apple tutorial does (or at least I think I am…)  [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm still having the same problem with this code, despite having defined only one `NavigationView`. The problem **came back** after I uploaded to Xcode 11.2, but in the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_release_notes) it doesn't say anything about any changes made to the `NavigationView`.

`first.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct first: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: second()) {
                Text("First link")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct first_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        first()
    }
}
```

`second.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct second: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: first()) {
            Text("back to first")
        }
    }
}

struct second_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        second()
    }
}
```

Video:

[image: demo of the problem]

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm getting the same problem even with the solution given below.

Comment: For your second question, I think you're looking for a programmatic dismissal.  Try this: [How to make a view dismiss itself](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current code is doing is nesting the `NavigationView` in `second` inside  of the one in `first`.

To get around this you just need to delete the `NavigationView` in `second`:

```
struct second: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: third()) {
            Text("second link")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I got rid of the NavigationView in the second view but still getting a display similar to the initial question.